# Swift: How can I make sure the seque does not run before the http task is finished?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, concurrency

I want the http task to run, setting the globally defined variable jwt. Then and only then do I want to run the seque that passes the jwt to my next activity.

I know that they are running out of order because the print statements are out of order. Capture is at the bottom. I redacted the actual jwt but where the black box is, is the jwt string.

***Main view controller***

```
import UIKit

var jwt = ""
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func submitLogin() {

    let url = URL(string: "http://example.com")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            print("Data is empty")
            return
        }

        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:.allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {

                jwt = json["jwt"] as! String
                print("Checkpoint 1 " + jwt)
            }
        } catch let err{
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

    task.resume()

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "loginSubmit" {

        if let toViewController = segue.destination as? HomeActivity {
            print("Checkpoint 2 " + jwt)
            toViewController.token = jwt
        }
    }
}

}
```

***Second View Controller***

```
import UIKit
```

class HomeActivity: UIViewController {

```
var token:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    renderInbox()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func renderInbox() {
    print("Printing token" + token)
}
```

}

[image: Output Capture]

P.S I have only been doing Swift for less than a week. So any general tips or the like would be welcome. Such as how to pass the jwt to the seque without using a global variable. Or what that is after checkpoint 1 in the output picture.

P.P.S Sorry about the code being in and out of the Stack Overflow code blocks. If you know how to fix it let me know and I'll try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a single button that triggers both a segue and a `URLSession` request. Since the request is asynchronous, the segue will always start before the request completes. The button triggers both at the same time, and there is no way that I know of to tell the segue to wait.

If you want the segue to start after the request, you'll need to remove the existing segue from the button (just click it and delete in Interface Builder), create a manual segue (with an identifier), and then present the segue manually using `performSegue`.

To create a manual segue in Interface Builder, control-drag from the `ViewController` icon (yellow circle with a white square inside) in the top bar of your source `ViewController` to anywhere in your destination `ViewController`.

[image: Screenshot of creation of a manual segue]

A menu will pop up and let you select what kind of transition you want. Once it's created, go to the Attributes inspector and set a descriptive identifier.

Now you add code in the URLSession's callback to manually invoke your new segue. Add this line right after "Checkpoint 1":

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "Your Identifier Here", sender: self)
```

Now your segue should happen only after the request is complete. This is also nice because if the request fails or you don't like the response, you can skip performing the segue at all.

Comment: It's painfully obvious now that you pointed it out. Thank you very much

Comment: @DavidRichards Most programming problems are. Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

No need to use segue here.
In the call back of the task, you can use `presentViewController` method to present the new view controller (or `pushViewController` if you have a navigation controller).